# MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint between Parent and Children

Tags: mysql

I am utterly disappointed as I failed to pinpoint to the exact reason, why my table creation is failing when I am trying to create a Foreign Key relation between my two tables. The SQL queries that I am using to create the 2 tables are as under:

```
CREATE TABLE `OneMD_DEA_EMEA_STG_CUSTOMER` (
  `Customer_Pkey` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CustomerID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `DataType` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `SourceSystemName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `SourceCountry` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `SrcDataRfrshDt` date NOT NULL,
  `StartDt` date NOT NULL,
  `EndDt` date NOT NULL,
  `Category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Customer_Pkey`,`CustomerID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `CustomerID_UNIQUE` (`CustomerID`),
  KEY `idx_OneMD_DEA_EMEA_STG_CUSTOMER` (`DataType`,`SrcDataRfrshDt`,`SourceCountry`,`EndDt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



CREATE TABLE `STG_RELATION` (
      `Relation_Pkey` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `RelationType` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `SourceDataType` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `SourceID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `TargetDataType` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
      `TargetID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
      `RltnPrmryID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `SourceSystemName` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `SourceCountry` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
      `SrcDataRfrshDt` date NOT NULL,
      `StartDt` date NOT NULL,
      `EndDt` date NOT NULL,
      `HCPHCOSubType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `HCPHCOLinkType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `HCOHCOSubType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `HCOHCOLinkType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`Relation_Pkey`,`SourceID`,`TargetID`,`RltnPrmryID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `Relation_Pkey_UNIQUE` (`Relation_Pkey`),
      KEY `idx_STG_RELATION` (`RelationType`,`SrcDataRfrshDt`,`SourceCountry`,`EndDt`),
      KEY `Source_ID_idx` (`SourceID`),
      KEY `Target_ID_idx` (`TargetID`),
      CONSTRAINT `Source_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`SourceID`) REFERENCES `STG_CUSTOMER` (`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `Target_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`TargetID`) REFERENCES `STG_CUSTOMER` (`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    CREATE TABLE `STG_RELATION_ROLE` (
          `RltnRole_PKey` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `SourceSystemName` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
          `ActivityID` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
          `RltnFrgnID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
          `SrcDataRfrshDt` date NOT NULL,
          `StartDt` date NOT NULL,
          `EndDt` date NOT NULL,
          `SourceCountry` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
          `HCPHCORoleType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `HCPHCORoleField` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `HCPHCORole` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
          `HCPHCORoleStatus` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`RltnRole_PKey`,`SourceSystemName`,`ActivityID`,`RltnFrgnID`),
          KEY `idx_STG_RELATION_ROLE` (`SrcDataRfrshDt`,`SourceSystemName`,`SourceCountry`,`EndDt`),
          KEY `Rltn_Frgn_ID_idx` (`RltnFrgnID`),
          CONSTRAINT `RltnFrgnID` FOREIGN KEY (`RltnFrgnID`) REFERENCES `STG_RELATION` (`RltnPrmryID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The Table RELATION got created successfully, but whenver I am trying to create the child table (RELATION_ROLE with parent as RELATION), the table creation is failing with the

> Error 1215: Cannot Add Foreign Key Constraint

error message.

Am I missing something here?

Please note that CUSTOMER is the main table with child as RELATION (Customer_ID acting as Primary and Foreign Key) which further has a child RELATION_ROLE (RltnPrmryID is the Primary Key while RltnFrgnID is the foreign key.

Please help me to get the issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, there are quite a few problems there - in particular with your table designs.

First of all, the `STG_RELATION.RltnPrmryID` is not the left most field of any indexes. MySQL requires both endpoints of a foreign key to be the leftmost fields of an index. The leftmost fields are the ones that can be used for lookups. This is the direct reason of the error.

Secondly, the primary key of `STG_RELATION` table is a mess. The child table should reference the primary key or a unique key from the parent table. `STG_RELATION.RltnPrmryID` is neither, it is only part of the primary key. `Relation_Pkey` field being auto increment already uniquely identifies records within the `STG_RELATION` table, therefore this should be the PK and `STG_RELATION_ROLE` table should reference this column in the foreign key (obviously, you need to adjust the field type for this to work in `STG_RELATION_ROLE`). Indexes on integers are a lot more efficient than indexes on strings from a performance point of view.